# Typo3 external typoscript editor?

Tags: editor, typo3, typoscript

Can anyone recommend an external text editor for Typo3 that handles typoscript color coding breakdowns and auto-suggests for code completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jEdit](http://jedit.org/) with [the TypoScript plugin](http://wiki.typo3.org/Enhanced_TypoScript_editing_with_the_jEdit_editor) is the best available choice, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: That is fantastic. I just downloaded it and installed the plugin and it works great! Thanks!

Comment: +1 , I use this too. It works very good.

Answer (score 3):

You might also be interested in this [DEV3](http://dev3.org/) project. TYPO3 editing for Eclipse. I expect it to grow further in the future, so maybe it's not the best option right now, but soon might be.

If you are on a Mac... Textmate with the [TS bundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/TYPO3.tmbundle/) is pretty good, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use NB-IDE PHP edition from www.netbeans.org with TYPO3 plugin
best solution for me!
cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows, you can use PSPad with the [sweeTS plugin](http://typo3.familie-redlich.de/sweets-typoscript-help.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also for TextMate, consider the [Cast Iron Coding tm.bundle](http://buzz.typo3.org/people/zachary-davis/article/textmate-bundle-typo3-extension-development/)...

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has a userLanguage as well: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2839067&group_id=95717&atid=612385